# Removing buttons from the html editor

Tags: html-editor

I've been searching the codex, and I'm probably overlooking something somewhere, but could someone tell if it would be possible to remove a [button/quicktag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZBTT.png) from the WordPress html editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `quicktag_settings` filter:

```
function wpa_47010( $qtInit ) {
    $qtInit['buttons'] = 'strong,em,link,block,del,img,ul,ol,li,code,more,spell,close,fullscreen';
    return $qtInit;
}
add_filter('quicktags_settings', 'wpa_47010');
```

The default is:

```
$qtInit['buttons'] = 'strong,em,link,block,del,ins,img,ul,ol,li,code,more,spell,close';
```

Though `'fullscreen'` usually gets added too at the end. So I just deleted the `'ins'` button.

**Edit to add:**

If you wish to create a custom button the [following tutorial](http://myownhomeserver.com/2011/10/wordpress-addremove-quicktags-simple-e) might help.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking! I'm sure I've read that article. Don't know how I might have misinterpret that one though.

Comment: welcome! i think in the article they advocate disabling buttons via filtering  $qtInit['disable_buttons'].  but i didn't see that in the source code anywhere.  http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/quicktags_settings?version=3.3&file=wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php

Comment: `fullscreen` is now called `dfw` (for *distraction-free writing*.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to this party I know, but might I add that it's better to be agnostic about the default buttons provided by Wordpress. So instead of typing the buttons you want, I choose to remove the buttons I don't want:

```
function nmt_quicktags_buttons( $qt_init) {
    $del_buttons = array('del','ins','img','code');
    $qt_init['buttons'] = implode(',', array_diff(explode(',',$qt_init['buttons']), $del_buttons));
    return $qt_init;
}
```

Now if anyone at Wordpress decides the quicktags-toolbar gets a new button, it will show up in your editor without a code change of your plugin/function.