# Remove specific buttons from wp_editor()

Tags: wp-editor

I know there are similar topics with accepted answers but I can't find what I'm looking for. I want to keep only basic buttons in `wp_editor()`. I'm using this in an option page to make writing more comfortable.

The problem is the theme adds a huge amount of quicktags I do not want on this specific page. How can I achieve this.

So far I've looked into `wp-includes/wp-class-editor.php` but the following line does not remove unecessary buttons :

```
'quicktags' => array('buttons' => 'link,ins,img,close')
```

:/ Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I've tried to modify function given in similar topic with this :

```
function wpa_47010( $qtInit ) {
global $my_plugin_page;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
      if( $screen->id == $my_plugin_page ) 
          $qtInit['buttons'] = 'link,img,close';
return $qtInit;
}
add_filter('quicktags_settings', 'wpa_47010');
```

But it does not work !

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47010/removing-buttons-from-the-html-editor you need to use the quicktag_settings filter

Comment: No that isn't simply because I do not want all editor to be restricted, I just want mine.

Comment: Wait maybe I can use some page condition.

Comment: Sorry, I've reread the question and have a clearer understanding of what you're trying to do, the code in the answer below works for me:

Comment: check the  perticular class from firebug  add  find that in wp-admin.css  and add display none for that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the settings API, you can use exactly the same code for calling wp_editor as you would anywhere else

I've test the code below, it adds a setting section to the reading section, and then adds a field to the section containing a WYSIWYG editor with buttons limited to link, img and close

```
// Add a setting to the reading page
 function register_plugin_x_settings() {
    // Add a section to reading settings 
    add_settings_section('plugin_x_setting_section','Plugin X (section caption)','plugin_x_setting_section_callback','reading');

        // add setting field
    add_settings_field('plugin_x_setting_wysiwyg', 'WYSIWYG Content', 'plugin_x_setting_wysiwyg_callback', 'reading', 'plugin_x_setting_section');
    register_setting('reading','plugin_x_setting_wysiwyg');
 }
 add_action('admin_init', 'register_plugin_x_settings');

 // function to render the section
 function plugin_x_setting_section_callback() {
    echo '<p>Plugin X Settings</p>';
 }

// function to render the setting
function plugin_x_setting_wysiwyg_callback() {
    // global editor id (not necesary, but we may need it elsewhere)
    global $myPluginEditorID;
    $myPluginEditorID = "myPluginEditorUniqueID";

    // settings to pass to wp_editor, disables the upload button, and sets minimal quicktags and turns off tinymce
    $settings = array(
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'quicktags'     => array("buttons"=>"link,img,close"),
        'textarea_name' => "input_{$myPluginEditorID}",
        'tinymce'       => false,
    );

    // output the wysiwyg editor
    wp_editor( "Content Here", $myPluginEditorID,$settings);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me, it adds an options page, and adds a WYSIWYG box to that page, with ONLY 3 quicktags: link, img and close, and nothing else.

Note, I turned of tinyMCE, and passed a settings array (which contains another array for quicktag settings) to wp_editor.

By passing in unique id of the textarea field, it will only affect the correct box on your plugin options page

```
// add admin page
function my_admin_add_page() {
    global $my_admin_page;
    $my_admin_page = add_options_page(__('My Admin Page', 'map'), __('My Admin Page', 'map'), 'manage_options', 'map', 'my_admin_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_add_page');

// render admin page
function my_admin_page() {
    // global editor id (not necesary, but we may need it elsewhere)
    global $myPluginEditorID;
    $myPluginEditorID = "myPluginEditorUniqueID";

    // settings to pass to wp_editor, disables the upload button, and sets minimal quicktags and turns off tinymce
    $settings = array(
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'quicktags'     => array("buttons"=>"link,img,close"),
        'textarea_name' => "input_{$myPluginEditorID}",
        'tinymce'       => false,
    );

    // output the wysiwyg editor
    wp_editor( "Content Here", $myPluginEditorID,$settings);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using it with settings API

Comment: Please could you clarify, are you adding wp_editor to an existing settings page, you should still be able to use part the code above to call wp_editor anywhere? see my second answer

Comment: I gave you points, I've decided to proceed the opposite way that is to say less options.