# How to remove buttons from the WP Editor on the edit post page in the admin area

Tags: customization, tinymce, wp-editor

I have a wordpress site that uses both standard posts and custom posts.

I have no problem removing buttons from the WP editor when it's related to a custom post type. I just add this below to the CPT plugin and reference the textarea I'm using:

```
$content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mytextarea', true);
$args = array(
    'description_name' => 'mytextarea',
    'teeny' => true,
    'quicktags' => false,
    'media_buttons' => false,
    'tinymce' => array(
         'toolbar1'=> 'bold,italic,underline,link,unlink,spellchecker',
         'toolbar2' => '',
         'toolbar3' => ''
    )
);
wp_editor( $content, 'mytextarea', $args );
```

So, I assume that, in order to do the same but this time for the edit post page, I have to go to the functions.php and do something similar.
But I don't know what to type instead of the 'mytextarea' reference.
I've looked for the html to find it out but whatever I try, it doesn't affect the wp editor on the edit post page. At best, it creates a new editor on top of it as this code creates a brand new editor before it customizes it.

So how can I target the already existing editor of the edit post page specifically in order to customize the buttons?

I tried many instances of hooks I found on the internet and over here but, for whatever reason, none worked so far. The editor remains stubbornly the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See this post [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114465/125227](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/114465/125227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can custom the editor with the filter `tiny_mce_before_init`

e.g. try this code

```
add_filter("tiny_mce_before_init", function ($initArray, $editor_id) {

    $initArray["toolbar1"] = "bold,italic,underline,link,unlink,spellchecker";
    $initArray["toolbar2"] = "";


    return $initArray;

}, 10, 2);
```